# Importing JSON data from SQL DB to an R dataframe

Tags: sql, r, json, dataframe

I would like to know whether there is a way of importing JSON data from a MySQL DB to an R dataframe.

I have a table like this:

```
id  created_at   json
1   2020-07-01   {"name":"Dent, Arthur","group":"Green","age (y)":43,"height (cm)":187,"wieght (kg)":89,"sensor":34834834}
2   2020-07-01   {"name":"Doe, Jane","group":"Blue","age (y)":23,"height (cm)":172,"wieght (kg)":67,"sensor":12342439}
3   2020-07-01   {"name":"Curt, Travis","group":"Red","age (y)":13,"height (cm)":128,"wieght (kg)":47,"sensor":83287699}
```

I would like to get the columns 'id' and 'json'.
I am using RMySQL package for getting the data from the db to an R dataframe but this gives me only the column 'id', the column 'json' contains only NAs in each row.

Is there any way how to import/load the data and get the json column displayed? And possibly to extract the "sensor" part of the json values?

The result would be a dataframe (df) like this:

```
id   json
1    {"name":"Dent, Arthur","group":"Green","age (y)":43,"height (cm)":187,"wieght (kg)":89,"sensor":34834834}
2    {"name":"Doe, Jane","group":"Blue","age (y)":23,"height (cm)":172,"wieght (kg)":67,"sensor":12342439}
3    {"name":"Curt, Travis","group":"Red","age (y)":13,"height (cm)":128,"wieght (kg)":47,"sensor":83287699}
```

Or with with the extracted value:

```
id   sensor
1    "sensor":34834834
2    "sensor":12342439
3    "sensor":83287699
```

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `unnest_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), 'db_name', user = 'user', password = 'pass', host = 'hostname')

t <- tbl(con, 'table_name')
  
t %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  transmute(j = purrr::map(json, jsonlite::fromJSON)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest_wider(j)


DBI::dbDisconnect(con)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  name         group `age (y)` `height (cm)` `wieght (kg)`   sensor
  <chr>        <chr>     <int>         <int>         <int>    <int>
1 Dent, Arthur Green        43           187            89 34834834
2 Doe, Jane    Blue         23           172            67 12342439
3 Curt, Travis Red          13           128            47 83287699
```

If you want to only retrieve data from the last 24 hours (as the OP requested) change the `tbl(con, 'table_name')` statement to:

```
t <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE DATE(`created_at`) > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY')
```

Comment: Thank you @kofm. And is there a way to transmute only the last 24hours of data in the table? The table is huge. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean without even retrieving it from MySQL or by filtering the table with dbplyr?

Comment: I mean subseting the data for last 24 hours  before unnesting the jsons, preferably without retrieving from MySQL.

Comment: Updated the original answer

Comment: Perfect, thank you, the subsetting works great but the unnesting part gives this error: Error: lexical error: invalid character inside string. ":"733","arg":"$u0027AT CMGF=1 u0027$u0027OK u0027$u0027 u0 (right here) ------^
Would you know what this means? Thank you very much!

Comment: I think it's fromJSON() that produces the error
Can you show the output of the dbGetQuery command?

Comment: You were right. There were different json structures. My last question would be, is there any was to unnest on deeper level? The unnested json has now columns which contain more records with multiple variables.

Comment: You could further unnest the resulting columns which contain multiple records

Comment: It may be specific to the data I'm testing with, but I think it's worth noting that `transmute(j = purrr::map(json, ~ jsonlite::fromJSON(.) %>% tibble::as_tibble())) %>% unnest(j)` (adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41991316/7418735) is about twice as fast as this solution, at the cost of readability.

Answer (score 0):

Converting your JSON response to a data frame should be straightforward but, because the structure of a JSON response is essentially arbitrary and you haven't given us details of how you obtain it or exact details of its content, it's impossible to give you code that will work in your specific case.  However, this is the basic process that works in one of my appliocations, starting with the post call to the API that provides access to the database.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

# Query the API
response <- POST(<your code here>)
# Extract the content of the response.  Amend the format an encoding if necessary.
content <- content(response, as="text", encoding="UTF-8")
#  Convert the content to an R object
content <- fromJSON(content, flatten=FALSE)
# Coerce to data.frame
df <- as.data.frame(content)
```

You should, of course, incorporate error and status checking throughout the process.

Note: your data contains a spelling mistake.  "wieght" should be "weight".